# Angular Directive to find parent elements margin-top

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to add the height of the parent element plus the margin-top of parent element to the element's height.
I'm using this directive but not working

```js
app.directive('sizetofit', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.getWidth = function () {
                return element[0].parentNode.clientWidth;
               };
            scope.$watch(scope.getWidth, function (width)       {              element.css('height', (element.parent().css('margin-top')+width/1.5) + 'px');
                 console.log(element.css('height'));
                });
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with the DOM elements?

Comment: @k4l4m I solved this by setting the elements css position : absolute and top equal to the margin-top of the parent element .So i got margin-top from the elemnts offsetTop property. So accordingly i set the height of the element

Answer (score 0):

> This is working fine. You can add in your code and check.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Arindam!';
}]);

myApp.directive('sizeof', function($timeout, $parse) {
   return {
  restrict:'A',
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
   
    console.log($(el).parent());
    $(el).parent().css({'height':'200px','margin-top':'20px'});
   
   
  }
   };
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div>
   <ul sizeof>
     <li>{{greeting}}</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```